# Can't store the value I am outputting in my stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I seem to be struggling with storing the values I am getting through my stored procedure into an existing column or even a temporary table. Here is what I have so far:

```
    USE `heatco`;
    DROP procedure IF EXISTS `totalPd`;

    DELIMITER $$
    USE `heatco`$$
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
    PROCEDURE `totalPd`(IN x int)
    BEGIN
        SELECT  
            A,B,C,D,
            ((A*(POWER(x,3)))+(B*(POWER(x,2)))+((C*POWER(x,1))+D)) 
            AS total
        FROM  heatco.pressuredrop;
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Whenever I try to store my total value calculated into something with an `INSERT INTO` statement I can't get it to work, it almost seems as if I must somehow store my total value as a variable.

I'd love if I could get some feedback on this!

Comment: Drop the stored procedure.. and Use the query   `INSERT INTO .... SELECT  
    A,B,C,D,
    ((A*(POWER(x,3)))+(B*(POWER(x,2)))+((C*POWER(x,1))+D)) 
    FROM  heatco.pressuredrop`

Comment: Why do you use both `use heatco` and then an explicit `heatco.` prefix?

Comment: @Barmar, probably to make sure the procedure will run correctly when the current db is not `heatco`. The OP is doing `USE` only before _creating_ the procedure.

Comment: @BillKarwin Ah, right -- so it's just using the default for where the procedure is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AS` just creates an alias for a column, it doesn't define a variable. You need to use `INTO` to sve the result in a variable.

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, ((A*(POWER(x,3)))+(B*(POWER(x,2)))+((C*POWER(x,1))+D)) 
    INTO @a, @b, @c, @d, @total
FROM heatco.pressuredrop;
```

But you can only do this if the query selects one row, so you probably need a `WHERE` clause to select the row you want, or maybe you should be aggregating the columns over the whole table.

You can also use assignments in the `SELECT` list.

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, @total := ((A*(POWER(x,3)))+(B*(POWER(x,2)))+((C*POWER(x,1))+D))
FROM heatco.pressuredrop;
```

This works with multiple rows being returned, but it overwrites the variable for each row selected, so `@total` will contain the value from the last row. But since you don't have an `ORDER BY` clause, it's unpredictable which row that will be.